# SASS theme - placeholder style inconsistency

Tags: user-interface, sass, kendo-ui, styles, placeholder

Is it a style bug or how can I make placeholder to be consistent between input with k-textbox style and textbox with icon:

```
<input class="k-textbox" placeholder="lighter color and shadow on focus" />

<span class="k-textbox k-space-right">
  <input placeholder="same color and no shadow on focus" />
  <span class="k-icon k-i-search"></span>
</span>
```

Demo:
https://dojo.telerik.com/UmuwUYeJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The placeholder color issue could be resolved by adding the k-input class to the nested  element:

```
<input type="text" class="k-input" placeholder="placeholder..."/>
```

The box-shadow issue is more tricky, as when the nested  element is focused, its parent box-shadow should be set. This can be achieved in two ways:

1. With JavaScript([Dojo example](https://dojo.telerik.com/IqIqABiG/2)):

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".k-textbox input").focus(function() {
           $(this).parent().css("box-shadow", "0 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.06)");
       });

       $(".k-textbox input").focusout(function() {
           $(this).parent().css("box-shadow", "none");
       });
   });
   ```
2. With CSS([Dojo example](https://dojo.telerik.com/UjoZUVIz)):

   ```
   .k-textbox:focus-within {
       box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
   }
   ```

The above used focus-within select has [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within), thus take this into consideration in case you would like to use the CSS approach.

Comment: I figured out the same. Thank anyway, for confirming situation :)